# Put only certain rows under a variable in R

Tags: r

I have a column called "BetterPerson" with values from 1 to 10.
I wanted to consider only rows with values equal or bigger to 6 and put them in a variable called conscious1.

How can I do it?

For example:
beauty is the dataset

```html
beauty$BetterPerson
[1]  6  5  6  5  8  2  8  5  5  9  9 10  5 10  7  8  6  5  8  6  4 10  8  8  8  2  3 10 10  6  6 10 10 10  9  7  5  5  2
[40]  7 10  8  7  9  7 10  4  4 10  9  7 10  4  3 10  6  4  8  5  7  6 10  7  8  6  7  5  3 10  2  8  6  8  1  5  3  8 10
[79]  4  8  6  6  5  7 10 10  3  9  7 10  5  6  9  7 10  8  7  5 10 10  9  7  2  7 10  8  3  9  6  5  9  9 10 10 10  5 10
[118] 10  7 10  9  6 10  7 10  9
```

and I want to put into "conscious1" only the rows with values >= 6 keeping also all the values under the other columns

Comment: use `subset(beauty, beauty$BetterPerson >= 6)`

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking about how to filter data? You can do that with `beauty %>% filter(BetterPerson >= 6)`.